Stein Complex Analysis Proof of Chapter 6 Proposition 2.5
In Stein's Complex Analysis book, within the proof of Chapter 6 Proposition 2.5, the following claim is made:
For $s = \sigma + it \in \mathbb{C}, n \geq 1$, then
$$\left| \frac{1}{n^s} - \frac{1}{x^s}\right| \leq \frac{|s|}{n^{\sigma + 1}} $$
whenever $n \leq x \leq n+1$, and $s = \sigma + it \in \mathbb{C}$?
Doesn't this fail for $Re(s) < 0$? For example, if $s = -2, x = n+1$, then the LHS is $2n + 1$ but the RHS is $2n$ $\forall n$, which clearly violates the inequality.
Here is the proposition:

Here is the part of the proof that makes the aforementioned claim.

Am I missing something?

The previous paragraph implies that one assumes $\Re s>0$ in the above
